# how to Install a DNN module with code instead of the interface?

Tags: dotnetnuke, dotnetnuke-module-mvc

I am developing a modue for a DNN website and i would like to make a little tool that is able to perform the installation process without having to go trough the CMS and install it with the extension installer.

This would probably be a lot faster. For this i need to know all the steps the installation follows and convert this to code. However Google does not seem to help me out here so far.

Does anyone have any information or code regarding this?

Answer (score 0):

Read this and the referenced links:

http://mitchelsellers.com/blogs/2009/10/14/dotnetnuke-bulk-extension-installation.aspx

Comment: One note on this due to some security changes is that you might not have the install.aspx file on your install.  You can get it back from the download of DNN if needed.  (NOTE not recommended to leave that in production at this time due to the security aspect)